# Can we set the timezone for influxdb.Chronograf?

Tags: influxdb, chronograf

I'm currently using `chronograf` to view my `point data` in `influxdb`.

At first the queried results in `chronograf` seem abnormal to me but I have later worked out the issue to be at `timezone` differences.

So `influxdb` could only store data in `UTC` timezone but `chronograf` is using my local machine's `timezone` to display the data.

**Example:**

In influxdb I have a point sitting at 7PM on a particular day but when I tried to look it up in chronograf, it is saying timestamp for the same `point` is on 5PM.

**Question:**

Is there a way for me to set the default timezone for my chronograf? This is so that it will not try to tamper my data and be showing the original timestamp at `UTC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** It is not possible to display data in UTC in `Chronograf` 1.3 yet.

`Chronograf` by default offset `influxdb`'s UTC data to whatever your local browser's time is.

I have raised a github issue to the Chronograf team and hopefully it will support displaying data in UTC soon.

See: https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/issues/1960

**Reference:**

https://community.influxdata.com/t/chronograf-set-to-use-local-or-set-timezone/947

https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/issues/1960

Answer (score 0):

Install this add-on/extension for Chrome/Chromium
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-timezone-time-shif/nbofeaabhknfdcpoddmfckpokmncimpj?hl=en

Install this add-on/extension for Firefox
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-timezone-time-shift/